# File writing in external storage device is not working

Tags: android, cordova

I tried writing a file to my android phone using phonegap ui.
I have given the write permission and i tried by using getExternalStorageDirectory() and by giving the absolute path. But still not able to write it. 
s1 is the name of the file that i am writing in the external storage

```
    Environment.getExternalStorageState();
//File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"/Android/");
                File file = new File("/mnt/sdcard"+ File.separator + "Android" + File.separator);


                if (!file.exists()) {
                    if (!file.mkdirs()) {
                        Log.e("TravellerLog :: ", "Problem creating Folder");

                    }
                }
                Environment.getExternalStorageState();
                File outputFile = new File(file, s1);
                FileOutputStream fileoutputstream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
                byte abyte0[] = new byte[1024];
                for (int i = 0; (i = inputstream.read(abyte0)) > 0;)
                    fileoutputstream.write(abyte0, 0, i);

                fileoutputstream.close();
                inputstream.close();
```

Comment: Have you added external storage permission to your manifest file ???

Comment: @user1645941: Yes.. I have included that in my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a quick working demo of writing a file to the external storage.

If this still doesn't work maybe it is a phonegap specific issue.

Hope this helps:

```
    InputStream is = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int bytes_read = 0;
    File inputFile = new File("/init.rc");
    File outputFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/testfile");
    try
    {
        is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
        os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        while ((bytes_read = is.read(buffer)) != -1)
        {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytes_read);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ignore) {}
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            is.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) {}

        try
        {
            os.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ignore) {}
    }

    if (outputFile.exists())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Success!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failure!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```